# How do I calculate the center of mass of an assembly by hand?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, reference-frames, mass

I'm doing some undergraduate research for my university in which I've recently been tasked with finding the center of mass of our assembly. I'm a lower level physics student so I'm having some trouble. I've googled it and tried many other methods of finding helpful information with no luck. I know I can use the CAD software I used to design it to find it. However, my research advisors also want a done by hand example/proof. I'm not asking for someone to find it for me. I just don't know where to begin in finding it myself. (I've attached an image of a basic example assembly. Not the actual one because I'm unsure if it is confidential or not.) If more info is needed I would be happy to add it. Thanks! [image: Example Assembly]

Comment: Hint: Devide the object into objects of a simple form, lets say cuboids, calculate the centers of mass of these simpler objects, then calculate the center of mass of the centers of masses.

Comment: If the cuboids don't have the same mass you have to take that in account by multiplying each cuboid with its mass and dividing by the total mass at the end (weighed mean): $\frac{1}{M}\sum_k x_k m_k$, where $M=\sum_k m_k$ (total mass) and where $x_k$ are the locations of the centers of math of each cuboid.

Comment: What exactly  are you asking? If you've taken intro physics you should know how to calculate the C.M. of an object, and how to sum up objects which are spaced at known distances.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft My physics professor showed us how to find the center of mass for particles and simple systems. Never really showed us 3-D objects and so forth. Sorry.